# Branch.io - AttributionListener onResult called when app returns to the foreground from the task switcher

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

In our app, the onResult method of AttributionListener is getting invoked not in response to the user clicking a link, but whenever the app comes to the foreground after another app was in the foreground.

We don't want to perform deep linking behavior if a link was not clicked.

In our case, the app was previously launched via a branch link or used a branch link to perform app launch or other in-app navigation. The next time the app comes to the foreground, it appears to this listener that a non-branch link was responsible.

Example:

1) Launch the app with all data cleared

2) Perform a navigation using a Branch link. Listener is invoked:

```
Branch referring params: {
      "$publicly_indexable": "true",
      "~creation_source": 2,
      "+click_timestamp": 154402....,
      "source": "android",
      "$identity_id": 59863755063006....,
      "~feature": "Share",
      "+match_guaranteed": true,
      "+clicked_branch_link": true,
      "$one_time_use": false,
      "~id": 5988882528627....,
      "$canonical_url": "androi",
      "+is_first_session": false,
      "~referring_link": "https://xxx.xxxx.com/dnNGtHR4oS"
    }
```

3)Open another app

4)Lock the device

5)Open the device

6)Open the original app from the task switcher

7)Branch listener indicates that a non-branch link has been clicked:

```
Branch referring params: {
      "+non_branch_link": "https:xxx.xxxxx.com/path and params",
      "+clicked_branch_link": false,
      "+is_first_session": false
    }
```

We use these referring params as an indication that the user clicked a link since there is no other information indicating otherwise.

Is there a way to either prevent the listener from running or to know that this is stale information?

Comment: are you find any solition for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for the Branch SDK to return the referring params that you are seeing when the application is launched from a non Branch Link or organically. "+clicked_branch_link" can be used to determine if the user clicked your Branch link to open the app. If this is false, you can assume that a Branch Link was not the catalyst for the app open.

However, you will always get these referring params even on organic opens.

Comment: I guess my issue is that I'm trying to know if the referring params came from a url click since we deep link from non_branch_link information whenever the listener fires. Maybe we shouldn't deep link from non-branch link?

Comment: To clarify, it would be useful to have a "+clicked_nonbranch_link":false if a "+non_branch_link":"https://" comes through from a non-click

Comment: @jchristof You can use the parameter '+clicked_branch_link' to determine if your deep link came from a Branch Link or a non Branch link.

Comment: Yes, but in step 7 above, when the app comes from the background, "+clicked_branch_link": false, but  "+non_branch_link": "https:xxx.xxxxx.com/path and params" but the params don't indicate that the link was not clicked, but is presented in the listener as a "default"

Comment: so as it stands, i cannot tell if this is a legitimately clicked link, or just a link provided by branch attribution listener.